# php paypal express checkout ssl error

Tags: php, paypal

I used the paypal express checkout for my payment integration. Its working on local server. While upload the files online it shows an error as `SetExpressCheckout failed: SSL connect error(35)`

I used the following class  for paypal express checkout

```
 class MyPayPal {

    function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode) {
            // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
            $API_UserName = urlencode($PayPalApiUsername);
            $API_Password = urlencode($PayPalApiPassword);
            $API_Signature = urlencode($PayPalApiSignature);

            $paypalmode = ($PayPalMode=='sandbox') ? '.sandbox' : '';

            $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t".$paypalmode.".paypal.com/nvp";
            $version = urlencode('109.0');

            // Set the curl parameters.
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

            // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);    

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
            $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

            // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

            // Get response from the server.
            $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

            if(!$httpResponse) {
                exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
            }

            // Extract the response details.
            $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

            $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
            foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
                $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
                if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
                    $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
                }
            }

            if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
                exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
            }

        return $httpParsedResponseAr;
    }

       }
```

Shall I need to add any `curl_setopt()` here. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please try: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 1);